# How to dynamicaly load and save user settings in WPF multi window application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, settings

I'm trying to save user setting in a WPF application. I want to save their Window position and size. To do so, I inspire myself of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidrickard/archive/2010/03/09/saving-window-size-and-location-in-wpf-and-winforms.aspx).

I change a little the save code to do the following :

```
 var oBaseProp = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["baseProp"];
            Properties.Settings.Default["baseProp"] = "1";
            System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("W_" + this.GetType().FullName + "_PLACEMENT"
                , typeof(string), oBaseProp.Provider, false, GetPlacement(this), System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.String, oBaseProp.Attributes,
                false, false);
            Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
            Properties.Settings.Default["W_" + this.GetType().FullName + "_PLACEMENT"] = GetPlacement(this);
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

BaseProp is a string property defined in my settings which is useless and just used to retrieve provider and other things.

Everything works fine for saving, I have a new file in C:\Users\christophe.mom.DOMAINE-EPSILOG\AppData\Local\Epsilog\MSSante_GUI.vshost.exe_Url_fkwxpmo4exiyrjk2vha2qu2upx5sgrvn\1.0.0.0 path, user.config that contains the desired data.

The thing is, I cannot load this file as settings file :

```
 void StandardWindow_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
            var sPlacement = (string)Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["W_" + this.GetType().FullName + "_PLACEMENT"].DefaultValue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sPlacement))
            {
                this.SetPlacement(this, sPlacement);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

I don't understand why my actual settings are not loaded. I tried in execution (not debug) mode too, and still no results.

Is someone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: It might be related to the event, You subscribed to. Try to check, whether the Handle is already created. If not, use another event to subscribe to.
And what means "not loaded" ?  Loaded but not applied or really not loaded with exception or whatever ?

Comment: I don't have any exceptions, I only not see my settings key in the defaut.properties, and it is present in the file on disk (not in visual studio cause all settings are done at runtime). I override onsourceinitialized instead of event, it doesn't change anything

Comment: So, in the debugger You cannot find the settings, which You correctly saved to disk under the proper indexer's ?

Comment: Yep, it seems like loading the wrong settings file (the one by default instead of the one in my appData directory)

Comment: Hmmm, according to code You tell to load Defaults. I know this approach by using XML-file and appConfig-keyword to store such settings.

Comment: But this settings (window size and position) must be individual for each window and for each user, this why I'm not using appConfig but UserSettings

Comment: Why do you even have to reload the settings? In my application they are loaded automatically

Comment: If I'm not reloading, it's the same. I just add it to see if it changes something but no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in fact, this works only on execution mode compiled in release (in my case).